# Screen cropped issue in unity 2-D game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d

I developed one 2-D game in unity. First I have run game on web player my screen is cutting from both ends. Now I am creating android apk from it. Then on android devices its also cutting from both ends. We are using free aspect ratio. I dont know much about screen size. So how to overcome from this problem?

CameraFollow.cs script-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float xMargin = 1f;      // Distance in the x axis the player can move before the camera follows.
    public float yMargin = 1f;      // Distance in the y axis the player can move before the camera follows.
    public float xSmooth = 8f;      // How smoothly the camera catches up with it's target movement in the x axis.
    public float ySmooth = 8f;      // How smoothly the camera catches up with it's target movement in the y axis.
    public Vector2 maxXAndY;        // The maximum x and y coordinates the camera can have.
    public Vector2 minXAndY;        // The minimum x and y coordinates the camera can have.


    private Transform player;       // Reference to the player's transform.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Setting up the reference.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        //camera.orthographicSize = 640 / screenwidth * screenheight / 2;
    }


    bool CheckXMargin()
    {
        // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the x axis is greater than the x margin.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - player.position.x) > xMargin;
    }


    bool CheckYMargin()
    {
        // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the y axis is greater than the y margin.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - player.position.y) > yMargin;
    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        TrackPlayer();
    }


    void TrackPlayer ()
    {
        // By default the target x and y coordinates of the camera are it's current x and y coordinates.
        float targetX = transform.position.x;
        float targetY = transform.position.y;

        // If the player has moved beyond the x margin...
        if(CheckXMargin())
            // ... the target x coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current x position and the player's current x position.
            targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, player.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime);

        // If the player has moved beyond the y margin...
        if(CheckYMargin())
            // ... the target y coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current y position and the player's current y position.
            targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, player.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);

        // The target x and y coordinates should not be larger than the maximum or smaller than the minimum.
        targetX = Mathf.Clamp(targetX, minXAndY.x, maxXAndY.x);
        targetY = Mathf.Clamp(targetY, minXAndY.y, maxXAndY.y);

        // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component.
        transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a 2D game, I presume you are using the **orthogonal camera**. Unlike perspective camera, the orthogonal camera shows more stuff on the screen the bigger resolution you have.

You need to normalize the [orthogonal size](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) to a wanted resolution:

```
 camera.orthographicSize = 640/screenwidth * screenheight/2
```

In the above code the orthogonal size is normalized to 640 pixel width. ([Link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/113641-Orthographic-screen-size))

Comment: where does that code goes? Every `Update` cycle? `Awake`? `Start`?

Comment: I have updated my code.so tell me where will be this formula used.

Comment: @letiagoalves If your resolution is the same for the duration of the game call it only once in Start or Awake.

Answer (score 0):

Free Aspect is just the current game view. This does not reflect what will be seen in the final product.  I recommend using one of the preset ratio's or if your up to date with Unity3d you can add your own custom resolutions.

So if you designing for phone when its vertical (GS4 used as an example) you can set it to 1080x1920. This will give you a better representation as to what you will see on your device.