# How to code for multiple versions of iPhone in Unity 3D?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D Game in unity 3D. In my game, i am using a tilemap to display the respective tiles on the screen. Each tile is of size 64*64 pixels. I am using Pixel units as 1 instead of the default value 100. My tilemap is a csv file of size 10 rows * 15 cols. If i change the device to iphone5, there is huge black area in the game.

My question is,

1. do i have to create multiple tilemap for each device? such as 10*15 (iPhone4), 13*23 (iPhone 5)
2. do i have to resize the tiles so that the tilemap exactly fits the screen? In this case the sprite might look stretched
3. is there Matix coding to adjust the Sprite and Camera?

If my questionis not clear, i can add more explanation. Your help is much appreciated!!

My layout for iphone 4 is (preferred layout)
[image]
But for iPhone 5 the layout becomes,
[image]

Comment: It depends on how you present your layout. Most similar games will add some decoration images on the "black area" you mentioned.

Comment: You'd better show some codes. At least you should show how do you draw the first tile / sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your camera's orthogonal size to the wanted resolution:

```
camera.orthographicSize = 640/screenwidth * screenheight/2
```

Change the 640 to your default screen width and put the code in a `Start` or an `Awake` function. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081438/screen-cropped-issue-in-unity-2-d-game).