# How to make game fit screen on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I'm developing a game, and in Unity I've set the resolution to 1280x800.
When I export to Android, I expect it to adjust to the screen (adding black bars if necessary) but it isn't the case.

This is how it looks like on a Nexus 4:
[image: Game on nexus 4]

And on a Nexus 5:
[image: Game on nexus 5]

How can I make it so that it looks the same everywhere? (having black bars if necessary as I said before).

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize the camera's orthogonal size to a wanted resolution:

```
camera.orthographicSize = 640/screenwidth * screenheight/2
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081438/screen-cropped-issue-in-unity-2-d-game)