# Unity - Trying to fit a game in an android screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started developing a video game as web, but I want it to run on an android device. It chops off a lot of the game. How can I make the game fit to the screen size of the device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **Orthographic** or **Perspective** camera? With *perspective* camera it might be an issue with the aspect ratio so you could just pull the camera back a bit. On *orthographic* camera you need to calculate the orthographic size for each screen size:

```
camera.orthographicSize = 640/screenwidth * screenheight/2
```

Put that in your Start or Awake function and change the normalized width to something that fits your project. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081438/screen-cropped-issue-in-unity-2-d-game).

Comment: I added that line to my script. Doesnt work. Where I can find the Norm. Width?